# Where can I modify to make a custom rom allow debug any apk without android:debuggable="true" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: rom, debug

I am try to debug a android app which have integrity check. Then I can not decompile it and change AndroidManifest.xml. And this app do not work in emulator. Therefore, I try to flash a custom ROM which can debug any app without flag android:debuggable="true" in my real devices. I tried changing the ro.debuggable=1 in default.prop in boot.img then flash to my device. But It did not change anything. Please give me some suggestion. Thank you very much. 
Edit: custom ROM I use is CarbonRom this is the link: https://basketbuild.com/devs/CarbonROM/.OLD/Nougat/sirius

Comment: Android stores the information about which app is debuggable in the file `/data/system/packages.list`. Therefore you can simply mark any app you want as debuggable after installation and without modifying the app itself.

Comment: I did not think every thing is simple like this. I will try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I try edit /data/system/packages.list but It did not work. I can not choose debug app in dev option.

Comment: The `Debug app` selector is a different topic. You were talking about the debuggable flag, which is definitely possible after changing the `packages.list`, I already did this and were able to connect to the app using the Android debugger.

Comment: Do you know how to select debug app after change packages.list? I can not choose the app I want to debug in developer option.

Comment: I assume this list is only updated when an app is installed. Try to restart the device. Alternatively you can always start the app with debugging via adb (`am start -D ...`).

Comment: Finally, I knew the problem. I don't need to choose at developer option. Just use the command you give me: am start -D [package]. Thank you very much.